# Find and list all factors of a given input integer DART

Tags: dart

As topic suggests, I came up with the solution presented below, but I feel it's quite dumb and could be rewritten in a much more efficient way.

Pls give me some feedback or suggrstions.

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  // the while true loop is here only so I don't have to hit RUN every time to check another nuber
  while (true) {
    // Prompts user for input ( on the same line )
    stdout.write("Enter the number: ");
    var userInput = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
    int divisor;
    int numberOfFactors = 0;
    var listOfFactors = [];

    for (divisor = 1; divisor <= userInput; divisor++) {
      if (userInput % divisor == 0) {
        numberOfFactors++;
        listOfFactors.add(divisor);
      }
    }

    // formats the display of end output( is that even in English? xD)
    var formattedList = listOfFactors.toString().replaceAll('[', '').replaceAll(']', '');

    if (numberOfFactors > 2) {
      print("Provided number is not prime, and the factors are ${formattedList}");
    } else {
      print(
          "Provided number is prime, because it has only two factors: ${listOfFactors[0]} and ${listOfFactors[1]}");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. You only have to check integers up to the square root of the input number. You won't find any bigger than that.

Comment: @Chris that's right but doing so it will only check if a number is prime or is not, but I also need to list all the factors, so even if it is prime I need to output 1 and the number . Or am I missing something? Feel like a kid in the fog :D

Comment: once you find a factor, keep trying to divide it in until it doesn't go any more. then move on to the next possible factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more optimized and fixed code of yours:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  while (true) {
    stdout.write("Enter the number: ");

    final userInput = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
    final userInputSqrt = sqrt(userInput);
    final listOfFactors = <int>[];

    for (int divisor = 1; divisor <= userInputSqrt; divisor++) {
      if (userInput % divisor == 0) {
        listOfFactors.add(divisor);
        if (divisor != userInput ~/ divisor) {
          listOfFactors.add(userInput ~/ divisor);
        }
      }
    }

    final formattedList = listOfFactors.join(', ');

    if (listOfFactors.length > 2) {
      print("Provided number is not prime, and the factors are $formattedList");
    } else {
      print("Provided number is prime, because it has only two factors: "
          "${listOfFactors[0]} and ${listOfFactors[1]}");
    }
  }
}
```

Some further optimizations there have been done:

- Removed `numberOfFactors` since we can just check the length of the list `listOfFactors` to see how many factors have been found.
- Simplified the creation of `formattedList` by using the `join()` method.
- Changed the type of `listOfFactors` from implicit `List<dynamic>` to explicit `List<int>`.
- (Not really an optimization but I have changed all non-final variables to final where possible to make it easier to understand which fields might change though the program)

Comment: Sorry for changing your answer a bit but I found it better than posting my own suggestions on optimizations. Only optimization I have done to your previous code was moving the `sqrt(userInput)` out of the loop and instead calculate this outside the loop. Reason here been that this value is not going to change and we therefore don't need to calculate this for every loop iteration.